# Clarification about apostrophe responsive images

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have some question regarding apostrophes `apostrophe-images-widgets` and its `srcset` functionality. It's explained in you Documentation under [Responsive Images](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/core-concepts/working-with-templates/responsive-images.html#an-image-widget-that-supports-srcset). I've implemented this solution but i think I misunderstood something becuase the delivered image is still `one-half` size as background of the parent div `focal-point-test`.

**I mean this:**

So the actual img with `srcset` attribute:

```html
{# lib/modules/my-image-widget/views/widget.html #}
<img src="{{ apos.attachments.url(data.widget._image.attachment, { size: data.options.size or 'full' }) }}" srcset="{{ apos.images.srcset(data.widget._image.attachment) }}" sizes="{{ data.options.sizesAttr or '100vw' }}" alt="{{ data.widget._image.description or data.widget._image.title }}">
```

Is in the the image but there is also a background defined for the parent `focal-point-test` with:

```html
{% set image = apos.images.first(data.page.main) %}
{% if image %}
  <div class="focal-point-test" style="
    {%- if apos.attachments.hasFocalPoint(image) -%}
      background-position: {{ apos.attachments.focalPointToBackgroundPosition(image) }};
    {%- endif -%}
    background-image: url({{ apos.attachments.url(image, { size: 'one-half' }) }})"></div>
{% endif %}
```

In this case two images will overlap one correct defined image with `focalPoint` cropping and the actual `img` element which has the `srcset` attribute but no `background-size: cover;`

I found out that you are hiding the img in your image widget:

```css
apos-slideshow .apos-slideshow-item img {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

So then the actual img with `srcset` would be hidden and the parent div in this case `.apos-slideshow-item` will deliver the image still in full size.

So I wanted to ask for some clarification what I have misunderstood in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apostrophe-images-widgets` module uses that double image technique specifically for when it contains multiple images and is acting as a slide show. That technique helps to maintain image appearance when the images are different sizes. That is why the `apos-slideshow .apos-slideshow-item img` CSS selector is hidden. The intention was that only the `background-image` would be visible.

> As an aside, and as a member of the Apostrophe core team, I can tell
>   you that this is an outdated strategy that we don't use anymore
>   ourselves very often, if at all. But it's hard to remove or
>   significantly change things like this once hundreds of sites are using
>   it.

If you are making your own images widget (which would be a good idea), I would not use both the `background-image` wrapper *and* a normal `img` tag. Decide on which works best for your use case. There are still good reasons to use both (maybe other variations on a slider), but that depends on the project.

If your goal is to use the focal point tool, a normal `img` tag with a normal `src` attribute won't be enough. One way is to use a `background-image` attribute on an element that you have set the size for some other way (e.g., `width` and `height` styles) with the `background-position` using the focal point values. *Another way* is to use `object-fit` instead, with the focal point values in an [`object-position` style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! That was exactly what I was wondering about. You suggested solution with `object-position` is definitely worth a try. I stumbled upon [this](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/) on my search. I think It would be possible to ad an helper to get the same values from `srcset` as `image-set` css rule.

Comment: Very interesting. I wasn't familiar with `image-set`. It looks like it still needs more browser support before being used in production, but it looks like a great new tool.