# Image cropRelationship for srcset

Tags: apostrophe-cms

If Implemented successful the `srcset` attribute for `img` tags regarding this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071639/clarification-about-apostrophe-responsive-images) about responsive images in apostrophe. I followed the suggestion to include only `img` elements and not mutliple img and div's with background-image styles. I used the `object-position` style to position elements with values from `focalPointToBackgroundPosition` that works pretty good for focal points.

Unfortunately I was not able to pass the cropping values to the image url's in `srcset` attribute. I mean the numbers and the end of an image name when the image is shown by the default `src` attribute with `apos.attachments.url` helper.

`/uploads/attachments/imagename.93.10.1745.873.full.jpg`

As far as I understood the code in `apostrophe-images/lib/api.js` it should be possible because you made this function already available with `cropRelationship` so I think there is something wrong in my code.

```html
<img data-image
  src="{{ apos.attachments.url(image.attachment, { size: data.options.size, crop: relationship }) }}"
  srcset="{{ apos.images.srcset(image.attachment) }}"
  sizes="(max-width:600px) 120vw, 58vw"
  alt="{{ image.title }}"
  {%- if apos.attachments.hasFocalPoint(relationship) -%}
    style="object-position: {{ apos.attachments.focalPointToBackgroundPosition(relationship) }}"
  {%- endif -%}
>
```

```js
{{ apos.area(piece, 'content', {
    limit: 2,
    widgets: {
      'card': {
        size: 'full'
        aspectRatio: [ 2, 1 ],
        controls: {
          cloneable: false,
          removable: true,
          position: 'top-right'
        }
      }
    }
}) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the solution. So if you want to use cropping for images with srcset you need to add `relationship` to `srcset` attribute like this:

```
srcset="{{ apos.images.srcset(image.attachment, relationshiop) }}"
```

Comment: If you find gaps in the documentation, please create an issue (or PR) in the documentation repo so we can be sure to clear that up. The core team should be doing a bunch of documentation work fairly soon.